# Difference between Web.Cache and ObjectCacheProvider of Ncache

Tags: c#, .net, caching, distributed, ncache

I am planning to use **Ncache** for caching application data in distributed applications. 
 
I am able to cache data using ObjectCacheProvider and NCache.Initiaize('cacheName') i.e Web.Cache.

What's the  difference between them??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object cache provide is just an integration for [System.Runtime.Caching Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and as it says:

> The System.Runtime.Caching namespace contains types that let you implement caching in NET Framework applications.

It basically allows you to switch to other caching platforms (which there are not many) with minimum code change.

Use the web api (below) to be able to use more features of [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/) otherwise stick to object cache provider.

```
NCache.Initiaize('cacheName')
```